# Cohomology of Heisenberg Group

Tags: group-theory, modules, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, projective-module

If we let $G :=$ the Heisenberg group over the integers, then I can show that the center of this group is isomorphic to the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ and that the abelianization of G is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}^2$. Can I use these two facts to more easily compute $H^2(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$? I am struggling to compute this second cohomology group and found hints to consider recasting the problem using the upper triangular matrices, but this doesn't seem to make the problem any easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Heisenberg group over ${\mathbb Z}$ consists of the $3 \times 3$ upper unitriangular matrices over ${\mathbb Z}$. This group has the presentation
$$G = \langle x,y,z \mid [x,y] = z, [x,z]=[y,z]=1 \rangle.$$
Note that the subgroup $Z = \langle z \rangle$ satisfies $Z \le [G,G] \cap Z(G)$, and $G/Z \cong  {\mathbb Z} \times {\mathbb Z}$.

So ${\mathbb Z}$ is a quotient group of $H^2({\mathbb Z} \times {\mathbb Z})$.

On the other hand, suppose that $H$ is a group with subgroup $Y \le H$ with $Y \le [H,H] \cap Z(H)$ and $H/Y \cong {\mathbb Z} \times {\mathbb Z}$, and choose $u,v \in H$ such that $H = \langle u,v,Y \rangle$.

Then $[H,H]$ is generated by commutators $[u^iv^j,u^kv^l]$ with $i,j,k,l \in {\mathbb Z}$. But since these commutators are central, we have $[u^iv^j,u^kv^l] = [u,v]^{il-jk}$ and so $Y = \langle [u,v] \rangle$ is cyclic.

So $H^2({\mathbb Z} \times {\mathbb Z})$ is cyclic, and it follows that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Sorry your notation is confusing me a bit. So you are showing that $G / \langle z \rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ (which is the abelianization of G). And from there deduce that the integers are a quotient group of the second cohomology?

Comment: Yes, but isn't that exactly what I wrote?

Comment: I was just clarifying, this solution makes sense thanks. Sorry the different fonts on Z's just confused me! Could you expand on the subgroup section of your argument, I don't follow how you conclude Y is generated by elements of H and the images generate the quotient?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was not clear! I have edited it.